# Please help idk if transmission, sensor or something else

Tags: transmission, chrysler, rpm

I have a 2010 Chrysler Town and Country minivan. I have recently had all the manintenance such as oil change, tune up and transmission flush all done as it was due. All of a sudden I was driving down highway and sped up as I was climbing a hill and it was as if the accelerator got stuck and the vehicle took off. Rpms were crazy high and the vehicle would not stop even slamming hard on the brake. This happened again few days later while pulling onto highway. Please any advice will do. I drive this vehicle for work so I need it, but also don't want to get screwed while getting a diagnostic check that's probably gonna cost me an arm.

Answer (score 1):

I had an older Town & Country that did exactly what you described. Couldn't put it in neutral or it would go to full throttle. So, had to hold the brakes and shut the engine off when there was a place I could stop.

What I found was that, while servicing the engine, someone had pushed the throttle and cruise cables out of the way hard enough to literally put a kink in them. This caused the cables to catch at certain positions. The cruise cable frayed to the point that any time I set the cruise control, the van would take off full throttle.

Lubing the cables did not help. I replaced the cables and the problem was solved.